# Language construct naming: Function/Goto

Tags: language-agnostic, function, goto

How is a language construct with the following properties called?

- It has a beginning and an end, just like a function
- It has a header containing it's name, also like a function but without arguments
- There can be any number of statements between its beginning and end, like a function
- You can use a function to jump to its beginning from anywhere (even itself) and it will execute the statements contained in it until it reaches its end
- You can use a function to immediately stop the execution of its contents and jump back where it was called from
- The code it contains is in the same scope as everything else, so you can access all variables outside and create new ones which aren't deleted upon leaving the construct.

All in all it is like a `goto` point with an end and the option to return where it was called from.

Comment: It is not my homework and even if it was, why would that be of your business? :)

Comment: @sub: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I just don't like it when I ask a question that doesn't concern a concrete problem or error message and the first response I get is "homework?". I have no idea a) what makes this question look like homework b) why a teacher would give homework like this, as you *can't solve the task as a student if you don't already know the answer* c) why nobody takes a look at my profile/the other questions I have asked. I suppose I don't seem like a student. d) why someone who obviously doesn't know the answer calls this homework. If you say that the question should be at least trivial to you, in my opinion

Comment: @sub: you've got to admit that a) how you formulated your question DOES make it look like homework, b) only being able to answer the question when you know the answer is kind of the point of a question isn't it? And c) your profile actually does look more like that of a student (no answers, just questions). Oh and d) "is this homework" is pretty much a standard phrase here on SO, "why would that be of your business?" certainly isn't.

Comment: @sub: in short, people are entitled to ask whether something is homework. The reason it's their business is because it affects how they answer - if someone is trying to learn then they don't want to just give a complete answer, they want to lead the student towards one. In this case, I don't immediately see how roe would give a different answer according to whether it's homework or not (unless perhaps he wouldn't answer at all in one of the two cases). Btw, I don't think you do have to admit (a), I don't think the question looks anything like homework. All that question for a one-word answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BASIC had this, it was called `gosub` and its only advantage over a proper function was your last point, where all of the variables were in the same scope. Beyond that it sucked.

In an object-oriented language, you could achieve generally the same effect by encapsulating the variables you want into an object and having different methods call each other. Multiple entry points are not a feature of most languages, but you can get around that by splitting your methods into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanks, I took a closer look at BASIC's gosub now and it seems exactly like what I'm searching for here. It'll be a subroutine then, I suppose.

Comment: @sub You might be interested in Python's and C#'s generators.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) may be relevant.

A closure is a function, but it's defined in some scope (another function, let's say), and it has access to all variables in that scope. So it has most of the properties you list except for being declared in a header and (usually) having a name. Headers are in any case a language implementation detail rather than a feature as such :-). Usually closures can be returned out of the function in which they're defined, and in a GC language they will maintain references to the local variables they use.

Also consider that Perl has two different kinds of scoped variables - lexical variables ("my") and dynamic variables ("local"). Lexical variables are the locals you're used to from C, Java and so on. Dynamic variables are visible from any function called from the block which declared them. So if all your variables are declared with `local`, all Perl functions have the desired properties.

In all cases, I missed "create new variables which aren't destroyed on leaving the function". That's pretty rare, since it sort of assumes that variables declared in functions have global scope, and that's not the typical case in most languages. You can normally fake it by having some global object and hanging stuff off that, but it's rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged "language-agnostic" i'd add that construct of `subroutines` is synonymous to the construct of `procedures`.

There are some language dependent nuances to `procedures` for example the SQL implementation:

- it has isolated scope (so that it doesn't mess-up innocent by-standing variables);
- it has an optional argument list with `IN`, `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters;
- it does not `return` anything, just alters the values of the `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters;

@Steve Jessop `Closures` are a very different kind of monster in my book.

While they do mimic many features of a `procedure`, they have their own argument list and call stack which makes them functions with access to external scope rather than a `procedure`/`subroutine`.

Answer (score -1):

From the structure of the program, I would call it a script. E.g. a shell/batch script.

Maybe task is a better name for that kind of structure, it can be a script using JavaScript or Perl that can be executed as is by just referring to the script itself.

Comment: What? Isn't a whole program written in a scripting language a script?

Comment: Sure, but a shell script is like a command that can be invoked by itself (recursion) or by another script (function), by prohibiting arguments it makes the construct hard to use in practice. Such a limitation will probably be circumvented by using global variables but that will lead to code that is very hard to maintain.